# Using super() instead of self in a child class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, methods

What is the difference between using `super()` and `self` in defining the `double_area` method in the subclass? It seems like `super().area()` and `self.area` do the same thing? Which one should be used, and why do they do the same thing?

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def area(self):
        return self.length*self.width

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*self.length + 2*self.width


class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self,length):
        super().__init__(length,length)

    def double_area(self):
        return 2*super().area()
```

Comment: try to redefine `area` in `Square` class to have a different behavior (like always returning 42) and you probably will see the difference

Comment: "why do they do the same thing" - now implement `Square.area` to return literally 5. Do `super().area()` and `self.area()` still return the same thing?

Comment: Because `super` is equivalent in this case, you didn't implement an `area` method in `Square`, so there's no need to skip it, hence there's no need for super. The `self` version should be used.